# Is this $\zeta(p)=\sum_{k\geq1 ,p\in \mathbb{P}}\frac{1}{{\sigma}_k(p)-1}$ true with sigma is power of sum divisor function?

Tags: prime-numbers, riemann-zeta, divisor-sum

let ${\sigma}_k(n) =\sum_{d|n} d^k$ is a sum of divisor function , And let ${\sigma}_k(n)$ be the iterating divisor function, We have for every prime $p$ and for every integer $k\geq 1$ : $${\sigma}_k(p)=p^k+1 \tag1$$ , Now form $(1)$ we have :$$\sum_{k\geq1 ,p\in \mathbb{P}}p^{-k}= \sum_{k\geq1 ,p\in \mathbb{P}}\frac{1}{{\sigma}_k(p)-1}\tag2$$, then :
$$\zeta(p)=\sum_{k\geq1 ,p\in \mathbb{P}}\frac{1}{{\sigma}_k(p)-1}\tag3$$ , Now my problem if i want to calculate for example $\zeta(2)$ I will get $1$ by $(3)$ ? then why that's not true however i have used correct formula ?

Comment: Your (3) is a nonsense. The Euler product is $\log \zeta(s)=-\sum_p \log(1-p^{-s})= \sum_{p^k} \frac{p^{-sk}}{k}$ where in number theory $\sum_p, \sum_{p^k}$ means sum over primes and prime powers

Comment: So what is the $p$ in the LHS of (3) ? (The title contains the same problem.)

Comment: is a prime number

Comment: OK, does the RHS depend on this one fixed prime number $p$? Could we use some other letter for the running letter in the undefined set $\Bbb P$?